# Execute commands using gMSA account

Tags: powershell, gmsa

I need to fetch the VM details using gMSA account

```
$Username = 'domain\gMSA-Auto$' 

Connect-VIServer -server 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -User $Username
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -WebOperationTimeoutSeconds -1 -Scope Session -Confirm:$false

Get-VM
```

I used gMSA to schedule scripts but don't have idea how to use it here.

Please if anyone can help me with it

Comment: gMSA accounts are not meant for interactive use. You can't impersonate a gMSA, can be used as service / process / scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon for your response. Then in this case gMSA account can't be used..?